# how to select a particular row from a Listview

Tags: c#, sql, listview

I want to extract a particular row with all the associated columns to be able to update a table.

The ListView is define like this : Id  Col1 Col2 Col3 CheckBox.

If the user select the 3rd row by clicking in the Checkbox, I am able to figure out whitch one the user selected by doing a foreach on the listview.  I want to know how to get the information from the listview row (basically I want to extract these fields and be able to assign them to my table columns name. After I will be able to update my table with the added values.)

```
protected void btnSoumettre_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int iCptCheckBox = 0;
    int indxChkBox = 0;

    foreach (ListViewDataItem item in ListView1.Items)
    {

        var chk = item.FindControl("MyCheckBox") as System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputCheckBox;
        if (chk != null && chk.Checked)
        {
            indxChkBox = Convert.ToInt32(chk.Value);
            iCptCheckBox++;
        }
    }

    if (iCptCheckBox > 1)
    {
        lblMessage.Text = "You can't choose more than 1 item";
    }

    else
    {
        using (ItemsDataContext rdv = new ItemsDataContext())
        {
            Items item = new Items
            {
               col1 = ListView1.SelectedItem[indxChkBox].SubItems[1].Text,
```

I tried this but it didn't find the SelectedItem and gave me an error.

Thanks

I am trying another option here

```
protected void ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ListView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        ListViewItem item = listView1.SelectedItems[0];
        docId.Text = item.SubItems[0].Text;
        doctorName = item.SubItems[1].Text;
    }
}
```

But i got the error The name ListView1 does not exist in the current context

Comment: web.ui does not contain a definition for SelectedItem

Comment: I will like to select the items from the third row and assign them to my tables fields to be able to update the table row.

Comment: What's the error you're getting? Also, just to straighten it out: you want to select a specific row and extract its contents into some variable or something (array for example)?

Comment: The error I am receiving is web.ui does not contain a definition for SelectedItem.    From the ListView i want to be able to extract the ListView row from the user selection (if user select the 3 third row of the Listview I will like to extract this data and put it in my table to update it.  Thanks

Comment: Is the second code block you just posted in the same class as the first?

Comment: NO Both are inside of the following class  public partial class Appointement : System.Web.UI.Page